# ASP.Net MVC 3 VB.Net Ajax request gives me a 403 forbidden error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I've been trying to make an Ajax call from my vbhtml page and I can't seem to get it working. I've been researching for a while now my problem but I can't seem to find an answer, maybe it is because I don't actually know exactly what to ask.

In my code i am trying to send the value that was selected in a DataGrid from [DataTables.net](http://DataTables.net) so that i can retrieve the information related to the selection and put it in some textboxes.

Anyways, I've been getting a 403 frobidden error when doing the ajax

Here's my View code

```
 function ShowInfos(selected) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Controllers/TelephonieController.vb/Show",
            data: '{nomEcran: "' + selected + '" }',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess,
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });
    }
```

Here's my Controller code

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
    Public Shared Function Show(nomEcran As String) As String

        Return "allo"

    End Function
```

(Sorry it's a bit in french)

This is the error it gives me

```
POST http://localhost:4390/Controllers/TelephonieController.vb/Show 403 (Forbidden)
```

I've only just started with Web so I might be a total newbie with this, but i have checked on the Web and people have been saying to take out ContenType or DataType and I've done both, I even tried sending and empty String with the Data but I can't seem to get it to work.

A bit off topic sort of, I tried an other way of doign ajax which is exactly this : [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381533(v=vs.100).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381533%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)
the problem is I can't seem to understand how I should send or could send a javascript variable to the controller.

If someone has a better way of doing things than what I am doing right now feel free to comment so I can learn.

Comment: Try `url: "/Telephonie/Show"`

Comment: it gives me : `POST http://localhost:4390/Telephonie/Show 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: Can you explain why you're using `WebMethod` on your function? I'm not suggesting that it's wrong if that's what you intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using `asp.net mvc3`, you can try `@Url.Action(...`

```
  url: "@Url.Action('Telephony','Show')",
```

You just need to provide controller and action name. Dont know why are you using TelephonieController.vb in url this isnt web form.

Though i dont have experience in vb, but still feels that vb would work like c#

Comment: I tried multiple alternatives to Url.Action() but none worked except `'@Url.Action("Show")'`, but even that would not reach my breakpoint in my controlelr it just went to the success function

Comment: `@Url.Action("Show")` worked after that I just had to fix minor glitches with my controller function and take out the dataType